# In scripts is partx better than fdisk for reading partition table?

Tags: partition

I have had some scripts, that used the output of "fdisk -l", fail on different versions of Linux, because the output of fdisk differs slightly.

The "partx --show" command appears to be standard on most systems (packaged along with fdisk).

If I convert scripts to parse the output of "partx --show", will these scripts perform better over time? Have your scripts that use partx been stable or portable across releases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest instead of either of those, using `sfdisk`, another part of util-linux. Why? sfdisk's manpage says explicitly says it is a "script-oriented tool for partitioning any block device", so I'd expect its output to be stable. (And AFAIK, `-d` output has been stable for a long time).

If you're writing shell script, `-d` output is probably easiest to parse. You can also use `-l` and `-o` to pick specific columns. If you're writing some other script (Perl, Python, etc.) and have a new enough util-linux ([around mid-2015](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/commit/?id=3c7fde5f922ce67ba773487e39f44db1eaa60f5e)), then `-J` will give you JSON.

Here's an example of how to use the `-J` parameter: `sudo sfdisk -J /dev/sda`. Its output looks like this:

```
{
    "partitiontable": {
        "label":"gpt",
        "id":"CA88994A-D99F-4347-89C2-6CCBC1B0765D",
        "device":"/dev/sda",
        "unit":"sectors",
        "firstlba":34,
        "lastlba":3907029134,
        "sectorsize":512,
        "partitions": [
            {"node":"/dev/sda1", "start":2048, "size":7811072, "type":"0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F", "uuid":"EABE31D7-1E43-4385-97E1-A8C9C4549C72"},
            {"node":"/dev/sda2", "start":7813120, "size":3899215872, "type":"0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4", "uuid":"EEBBAB54-0A5A-4B3F-9BEB-4FE10350EE2F"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: and if you are using GPT partitions, you can use `sgdisk`.